# Sheaf of rational functions on algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I am trying to understand sheaf of rational functions of an algebraic stack. As given in nLab https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheaf+of+rational+functions, the definition holds in particular for algebraic stacks (considering any ringed topos of the algebraic stack, say fppf or lisse-etale). But can there be a more explicit description for the case of algebraic stacks?

In the short paper, *[Misconceptions about $K_X$](http://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=ens-001:1979:25::372)* by Kleiman, one can find how the sheaf of rational functions behaves on schemes with nice properties like
'reduced with locally finite irreducible components'. I want to understand similar cases for algebraic stacks. Can someone suggest some reference in this regard?

Thanks in advance!